# RubyMine autocomplete suggestions are slow. Is there a way to speed them up?

Tags: rubymine

I work on a large monolith of a project. As such, my RubyMine suggestions while typing take a long time. Long enough that I always complete the word before any suggestion pops up. I have to stop typing and wait about a second before I will receive any suggestions. This makes the feature essentially worthless, as I always type fast enough that I won't get any autocomplete.

I have tried increasing RubyMine's memory. Is there anything else I can do, or is this just something you have to deal with working on a large project?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preferences (Cmd + ,) => Editor > General => Code Completion and set the 'Autopopup documentation in (ms):' to 0 as well as the 'Autopopup in (ms):' to 0.